# Encrypted LVM automount at boot with key on another server

Tags: lvm, disk-encryption

I'd like to protect the data on my Linux server from physical theft by using encrypted partitions with a keyfile stored on another server on my network. The other server would actually be my router, which is very small, in a different physical location to the server, and accessible over ssh.

I figure the chances of someone stealing the server from one location, breaking into a second location, finding and stealing the router, and subsequently setting them both up in the same network, are pretty slim. It means my server will always reboot and start all services as long as it's connected to my network, but my important data is protected if it ever leaves the building.

The boot sequence would be something like:

- mount non-encrypted logical partitions (`/`, `/var`, `/tmp` etc.)
- start networking
- obtain key from the other server over ssh
- unlock the encrypted physical partition
- mount the encrypted logical partitions (`/home`, `/opt` etc.)
- start other services which will have been configured to use the encrypted partitions - e.g. Docker

I don't know how to hook into the LVM / crypto boot sequence to insert a script to get the key, nor do I know how to change the boot sequence so that the network is started before that step.

The root user on the Linux box would have an ssh key set up on the router such that it could ssh with no password, something like:

```
PASSPHRASE=$(ssh router cat /config/disk-passphrase.txt)
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda6 sda6_crypt <<< $PASSPHRASE
```

This is the disk layout I have so far, although I'm open to changing it if necessary:

```
NAME                         FSTYPE    LABEL UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda
├─sda2
├─sda5                       LVM2_memb       fjRt18-XKFm-z3RN-1D7t-zkuw-sMal-KyOZ6Z
│ ├─garage--main--vg-tmp     ext4            e90a6186-bf09-41f7-b8bc-392e0fba2207   /tmp
│ ├─garage--main--vg-var     ext4            ee878d29-3b44-463f-adba-083155ea29da   /var
│ └─garage--main--vg-root    ext4            f4fa0962-3c2c-456c-9ee0-84c47d6c12c9   /
├─sda1                       ext4            60d06dea-a07b-4af3-bf30-70fa3f82267d   /boot
└─sda6                       crypto_LU       31b7b643-188c-4ae9-bac6-75316b37d562
  └─sda6_crypt               LVM2_memb       ynUOJB-iRsP-djql-Tzrl-nfHh-Smga-ji4OcT
    ├─garage--enc--vg-opt    ext4            2f149989-f64c-4cab-8a47-fea80ebf4c8e   /opt
    ├─garage--enc--vg-swap_0 swap            bab96476-7209-42c7-9f2a-113dd5c4da67   [SWAP]
    └─garage--enc--vg-home   ext4            c73b9432-ec32-412c-baa4-1329adef9c56   /home
```

Comment: Note that in addition to stealing the router along with your server, another attack is possible: an attacker could extract the SSH private key from your server (which must necessarily be stored unencrypted) and use this to get the disk encryption key from your router. In essence, this would be an evil maid attack but without the need for you to log in after the attack happens.

Comment: One way could be to flag the mounts on the encrypted volume as `noauto` in fstab, then define a service which needs network, does the decryption and mount of the partitions, and then provides a service which you have to define as requested by the services which use the partitions on the encrypted volume.

Comment: @JosephSible technically true, but they wouldn't be able to ssh to my router from outside the house as the port is only open on the LAN side. [The router](https://www.ubnt.com/edgemax/edgerouter-x/) is seriously small and fairly well hidden in my house, powered over PoE from the switch in the garage. That's not really the scenario I'm trying to prevent anyway- if someone steals the server I'd just like to be able to say that it's highly unlikely they have any of my data.

Comment: I meant they'd carry out that attack while the server is still where it belongs (such as by just live booting it), then take it after they get the key.